# UIPinchGestureRecognizer not called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, mkmapview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have a single view on my iOS application, with a mapView in it.
When adding a tap or long press recognizer, the events are properly called.
But not with the pinch event...

```
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *handlePinchGesture=[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:mapView action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [mapView addGestureRecognizer:handlePinchGesture];
```

Any idea what I should add ?
Thanks.

Comment: Show the `handlGesture:` method

Comment: The handleGesture function is not called (I have set a breakpoint at line 1, and it is not reached).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `mapView` is an `MKMapView`, it has its own pinch gesture recognizer for zooming the map.

If you want to add your own recognizer, you have to allow it to recognize simultaneously with the other (mapview-controlled) recognizer. Set your gesture recognizer's `delegate` and implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` (you can just always return `YES`).

You should also probably set `self` as the gesture recognizer's `target` and not the `mapView`.

Comment: Even adding this function doesn't fire my handlePinchGesture function (I have set a breakpoint at line 1, and it is not reached). So I added a delegate of handlePinchGesture to self, but and now when I pinch, the code crashes... In my xib, I have no delegate. Can it be linked ?

Comment: What exactly crashes the code? Have you set the delegate or not? Just implementing this method without setting the delegate won't do anything...

Comment: "unrecognized selector sent to instance". In my xib, I can't find the delegate object...

Comment: The delegate has nothing to do with your xib. Do something like `handlePinchGesture.delegate = self` in your code.

Comment: That's what I did, and after that I get the "unrecognized selector" issue when I pinch.

Comment: I see, I think I know what the issue is then. Could it be that your `handleGesture` method doesn't take any parameters? In that case, you have to use `@selector(handleGesture)` and not `@selector(handleGesture:)` (note the missing colon) when you add the gesture recognizer.

Comment: Unfortunately it has a parameter (sender)... Any other idea ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the unrecognized selector's name?

Comment: @LaurentCrivello: Better yet, what is the **complete error message** that *starts with* “unrecognized selector”?

Comment: That's the message:"-[MKMapView handleGesture:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b91550", and that's the function: "-(void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender"

Comment: Ah, overlooked that. You should use `self` as the target and not `mapView`.

Answer (score 1):

In the handleGesture method did you do something like this:

```
CGFloat beginPinch;  //declare this as your ivars

-(void)handleGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchRecognizer
{
    if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        beginPinch = pinchRecognizer.scale;    
    } 
    else if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        if (pinchRecognizer.scale < beginPinch)
        {
              //do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even the first line is not reached. The function is not called.

Comment: Looked like omz discovered the error.  Should have caught it myself!